# How to select multiple checkboxes in qtp

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Can some one explain how to select multiple check-boxes in a web table using for loop by taking the number of rows dynamically in QTP.
My issue was i have to select check box(s) base on the number of rows present in a web table but the rows are not constant. Please help in this.

Comment: Totally depends. On your webtable's structure. Record one click, then one click a row below the first, and post that.

Answer (score 0):

an option is to get the table object, find the children checkboxes and select them. It really depends on your table structure and how the objects are embedded. If you could provide more details , perhaps we can be of more help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You will recive arraylist of checkbox objects. If you want to select all values just delete lines about arrayList. I dont have IDE at this moment, but this should work.

```
Function FnGetCheckboxes()
    Set objDesc = Description.Create
    objDesc("micclass").value = "checkbox"
    Set objTempCollection = Browser("").Page("").WebTable("").Childobjects(objDesc)
    Set objArrList = createObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For intI = 0 to objTempCollection.Count-1
        objArrList.add objTempCollection(intI)
    Next

    Set FnGetCheckboxes = objArrList
    Set objArrList = Nothing
    Set objTempCollection = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically find the number of rows for the table using RowCount and use the RowCount as the upper boundary limit for the "FOR" loop. Example

```
dynamicRowCount = Browser("name:=.*@gmail.com - Gmail").Page("title:=.*@gmail.com - Gmail").WebTable("name:=Not Started").RowCount
For i=2 To dynamicRowCount Step 1
    'WRITE THE CODE TO CLICK ON THE CCHECKBOXES
Next
```

where dynamicRowCount returns the number of rows at runtime.